# How can I change the domain name of localhost in wos2is?

Tags: dns, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have installed and configured wso2is on a server, but I have no idea how I can change the wsois domain. When you start wso2is, the default domain is localhost. And that I want to change so that other users on the same network can connect. I don't know if I explain well, I feel it's a stupid question.

Thank you in advance,

Antonio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have simple installation usually it's enough to define two properties in

`repository/conf/carbon.xml`:

```xml
<HostName>my-host-name</HostName>
<MgtHostName>my-host-name</MgtHostName>
```